# Spoon + TeamCity

Tags: android, teamcity, robotium, spoon

I want to test my app using Spoon + TeamCity. TeamCity is a remote server, is it possible to get access to android devices to run Spoon tests from TeamCity? Has anybody faced this problem?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Interface Android robotium testing with Teamcity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606080/interface-android-robotium-testing-with-teamcity)

Comment: if you're devices are connected to the TeamCity agents then you should be able to use them or are you talking about something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

https://bitbucket.org/sproshev/gcm-notifier

If this doesn't do it you could do something creating like have a file copy to a share and have a script that is waiting for that file.